# Django Channels session is not persistent. disconnect -> logged out

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-channels, django-sessions, django-login

I have a websocket-router:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': 
    AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url("ws/", Consumer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

I am logging in a user by sending a command to the websocket. The user gets logged in like this:

```
if cmd == 'login':
    user = await database_sync_to_async(authenticate)(consumer.scope, email=request['eMail'], password=request['pass'])
    if user is not None:
        # login the user to this session.
        await login(consumer.scope, user, backend='allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend')
        # save the session
        consumer.scope['session'].modified = True
        await database_sync_to_async(consumer.scope['session'].save)()
```

Every time, the websocket-connection gets disconnected, the user is not logged in anymore.
I thought, the session gets saved by

```
consumer.scope['session'].save()
```

but it doesn´t work. The session is not persistent.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which session backend are you using in Django.

Due to how web sockets work once the connection is created you can't set any cookies so if your using a session backend that depends on cookie storage the `save` will have no effect since the web-browser can't be updated.

Currently channels does not even support setting cookies durring the accept method.  https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1096#issuecomment-619590028

However if you ensure that you users already has a session cookie then you can `upgrade` that session to a logged in user.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this was the reason, I think. I used the regular backend of Django. So my solution now is that I create JWTs (Json Web Tokens) and save them in the localStorage of the browser. This way, I can login while connected to the websocket.

Comment: @matthaus-woolard In your answer, did you mean "do this IN the `accept` method", or "do this BEFORE the `accept` method"?

Comment: @DanSwain yer... well theoretically one should be able to do this in the `accept` method however i just double checked and it seems Django Channels does not propogate session cookies even from there :(